# Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` of type `array` supplied to `Query`, expected `function`

Tags: reactjs, graphql

here i want to call the graphql query in the class component but getting the same problem again and agian :

TypeError: children is not a function,
Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` of type `array` supplied to `Query`, expected `function`.

```
const GET_USERS = gql`

query{
  users{
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    Email,
    Gender,
    Password,
    _id
  }
}
`;
  return (
      <Query query={GET_USERS}>
      {({ loading, error, data }) => {
    if (loading) return 'Loading...';
    if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;
   <div>...some jsx herer</div>
}}
);
```

Comment: Your question is not complete and I'm not able to understand what you're asking. The error is clear thu I don't think your problem is related to that.
Provide more code for clarification.

Comment: Sir exactly i have used below code for getting Query response but all time i am getting "children is not a function" Error

Code:-

 <Query query={GET_USERS} >
      {({ loading, error, data }) => {
        
        console.log("loading", loading)
        console.log("error", error)
       console.log("data", data)
      }};
      </Query>


So please let me know some usefull solution

Comment: Even this query working fine in graphQl playground

Comment: Try to make a simple reproducible example on codesandbox please

Answer (score 0):

did you resolve it . I think it be because that children in react is array. 
but in component Query children must be a function. and you can review this problem 
in any component which call children like  this 'clildren()'; and you can resolve it by add the children tag to Query Component;
I'm so sorry with my  poor English;